# Using scp to transfer a single file into a remote folder that doesn't exist

Tags: python, scp

I'm working on a python script that monitors a directory and uploads files that have been created or modified using scp. That's fine, except I want this to be done recursively, and I'm having a problem if a user creates a directory in the watch directory, and then modifies a file inside that new directory.

I can detect the directory creation and file nested file creation/modification just fine. But if I try to upload that file to the remote server, it won't work since the directory on the remote site won't exist. Is there a simple way to do this WITHOUT recursively copying the created directory? I want to avoid this because I don't want to delete the remote folder if it exists.

Also, please don't suggest `rsync`. It has to only use ssh and scp.

Comment: have you tried the `-r` modifier? (`-r` means "do this copy recursively" and constructs the folders as needed)

Comment: Why can't you use rsync? Is it just that you don't like it? Do you have a real reason for not using it? If so, what's the reason? When you ask "How do I do A? Please don't suggest tool B" and the usual answer to "How do I do A?" is "Use tool B" and you don't say *why* you can't use tool B, it tends to rub people the wrong way. Also, if you tell us why you can't use it, it'll help us to come up with a better answer.

Comment: Well first of all I don't like rsync, but that's not why I say I don't want to use it. I've found rsync is extremely slow, much slower than scp for the type of transfers I'm doing. Also, rsync doesn't even solve my problem. I'm trying to do this manually so I don't have the overhead of rsync's difference calculations. I don't want it to have to calculate a whole difference tree every time a file was updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have ssh, can't you just create the directory first?  For example, given a file with absolute path /some/path/file.txt, issue a `mkdir -p /home/path` before uploading `file.txt`.

UPDATE:  If you're looking to lower the number of transactions, a better method might be to make a tar file locally, transfer that, and untar it.

Comment: This is the only solution I could think of. I was just hoping there would be a way to do this in 1 transaction via scp without relying on mkdir to fail

Comment: @Falmarri, see my update.  Not sure that there are any better ways beyond that.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably go with creating the directory over ssh

Answer (score 1):

While I imagine your specific application will have its own quirks (as does mine), this may put you on the right path.  Below is a short snippet from a script I use to put files onto a remote EC2 instance using Fabric built on paramiko.  Also note I where I put the sudo commands as Fabric has its own "sudo" class.  This is one of those quirks I was referring to.  Hope this helps someone.

```
from fabric.api import env, run, put, settings, cd
from fabric.contrib.files import exists
```

'''
sudo apt-get install fabric
Initially setup for interaction with an AWS EC2 instance
At the terminal prompt run:
fab ec2 makeRemoteDirectory changePermissions putScript
'''

TARGETPATH = '/your/path/here'

def ec2():
    env.hosts = ['your EC2 Instance or remote address']
    env.user = 'user_name'
    env.key_filename = '/path/to/your/private_key.pem'

def makeRemoteDirectory():
    if not exists('%s'%TARGETPATH):
        run('sudo mkdir %s'%TARGETPATH)

def changePermissions():
    run('sudo chown -R %(user)s:%(user)s %(path)s'%{'user': env.user, 'path': TARGETPATH})

def putScript():
    fileName = '/path/to/local/file'
    dirName = TARGETPATH
    put(fileName, dirName)

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly scp, but sftp can take the `-b` parameter with a batch file. You can send a mkdir and a put.